# Enabling TLS on local RabbitMQ installation

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq

everyone. I've been trying to enable TLS on RabbitMQ for a while now with no success.
I have a local installation of rabbit starting up correctly, but the configures TLS port is not responding, this is what I get when I attempt to connect through openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:5671 -cert client_certificate.pem -key client_key.pem -CAfile ca_certificate.pem
```

And this is the output.

```
Enter pass phrase for client_key.pem:
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 293 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Certificates seem to be sent to the server, but nothing is returning. Rabbit logs show nothing at all.
I've seen similar questions to this but they were resolved by changing permissions on the certificates and key for rabbit to be able to read them. In my case this files are completely open, as you can see in the image below they have 777 permissions:

[file permissions][1]

This is my rabbitmq.conf file:

```
 listeners.ssl.default = 5671
 ssl_options.verify = verify_peer
 ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
 ssl_options.cacertfile = /etc/rabbitmq/ca_certificate.pem
 ssl_options.certfile = /etc/rabbitmq/server_certificate.pem
 ssl_options.keyfile = /etc/rabbitmq/server_key.pem
 ssl_handshake_timeout = 20000
 management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

I can see that this rabbitmq.conf is loaded succesfully since the output on rabbit startup shows that definitions.json is correctly loaded:

```
2020-12-04 11:52:38.902 [info] <0.520.0> Applying definitions from file at '/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.
```

And also that the ssl listener is enabled:

```
 2020-12-04 11:52:39.087 [info] <0.849.0> started TLS (SSL) listener on [::]:5671
```

Here is the output of rabbitmq-diagnostics environment command:

```
Application environment of node rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490 ...
[{amqp_client,
     [{prefer_ipv6,false},{ssl_options,[]},{writer_gc_threshold,1000000000}]},
 {asn1,[]},
 {aten,
     [{detection_threshold,0.99},
      {heartbeat_interval,100},
      {poll_interval,5000},
      {scaling_factor,1.5}]},
 {compiler,[]},
 {cowboy,[]},
 {cowlib,[]},
 {credentials_obfuscation,[{enabled,true}]},
 {crypto,[{fips_mode,false},{rand_cache_size,896}]},
 {cuttlefish,[]},
 {gen_batch_server,[]},
 {goldrush,[]},
 {inets,[]},
 {jsx,[]},
 {kernel,
     [{inet_default_connect_options,[{nodelay,true}]},
      {inet_dist_listen_max,25672},
      {inet_dist_listen_min,25672},
      {logger,
          [{handler,default,logger_std_h,
               #{config => #{type => standard_io},
                 formatter =>
                     {logger_formatter,
                         #{legacy_header => true,single_line => false}}}}]},
      {logger_level,notice},
      {logger_sasl_compatible,false},
      {shutdown_func,{rabbit_prelaunch,shutdown_func}}]},
 {lager,
     [{async_threshold,20},
      {async_threshold_window,5},
      {colored,false},
      {colors,
          [{debug,"\e[0;38m"},
           {info,"\e[1;37m"},
           {notice,"\e[1;36m"},
           {warning,"\e[1;33m"},
           {error,"\e[1;31m"},
           {critical,"\e[1;35m"},
           {alert,"\e[1;44m"},
           {emergency,"\e[1;41m"}]},
      {crash_log,"log/crash.log"},
      {crash_log_count,5},
      {crash_log_date,"$D0"},
      {crash_log_msg_size,65536},
      {crash_log_rotator,lager_rotator_default},
      {crash_log_size,10485760},
      {error_logger_format_raw,true},
      {error_logger_hwm,5000},
      {error_logger_hwm_original,50},
      {error_logger_redirect,true},
      {extra_sinks,
          [{error_logger_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_channel_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_connection_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_feature_flags_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_federation_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_ldap_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_mirroring_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_prelaunch_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_queue_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_ra_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_shovel_lager_event,
               [{handlers,[{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_forwarder_backend,[lager_event,info]}]}]},
           {rabbit_log_upgrade_lager_event,
               [{handlers,
                    [{lager_file_backend,
                         [{date,[]},
                          {file,
                              "/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490_upgrade.log"},
                          {formatter_config,
                              [date," ",time," ",color,"[",severity,"] ",
                               {pid,[]},
                               " ",message,"\n"]},
                          {level,info},
                          {size,0}]}]},
                {rabbit_handlers,
                    [{lager_file_backend,
                         [{date,[]},
                          {file,
                              "/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490_upgrade.log"},
                          {formatter_config,
                              [date," ",time," ",color,"[",severity,"] ",
                               {pid,[]},
                               " ",message,"\n"]},
                          {level,info},
                          {size,0}]}]}]}]},
      {handlers,
          [{lager_file_backend,
               [{date,[]},
                {file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490.log"},
                {formatter_config,
                    [date," ",time," ",color,"[",severity,"] ",
                     {pid,[]},
                     " ",message,"\n"]},
                {level,debug},
                {size,0}]}]},
      {log_root,"/var/log/rabbitmq"},
      {rabbit_handlers,
          [{lager_file_backend,
               [{date,[]},
                {file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490.log"},
                {formatter_config,
                    [date," ",time," ",color,"[",severity,"] ",
                     {pid,[]},
                     " ",message,"\n"]},
                {level,debug},
                {size,0}]}]}]},
 {mnesia,[{dir,"/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490"}]},
 {observer_cli,[{plugins,[]}]},
 {os_mon,
     [{start_cpu_sup,false},
      {start_disksup,false},
      {start_memsup,false},
      {start_os_sup,false}]},
 {prometheus,[]},
 {public_key,[]},
 {ra,[{data_dir,
          "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490/quorum"},
      {logger_module,rabbit_log_ra_shim},
      {wal_max_batch_size,4096},
      {wal_max_size_bytes,536870912}]},
 {rabbit,
     [{auth_backends,[rabbit_auth_backend_internal]},
      {auth_mechanisms,['PLAIN','AMQPLAIN']},
      {autocluster,
          [{peer_discovery_backend,rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config}]},
      {autoheal_state_transition_timeout,60000},
      {background_gc_enabled,false},
      {background_gc_target_interval,60000},
      {backing_queue_module,rabbit_priority_queue},
      {channel_max,2047},
      {channel_operation_timeout,15000},
      {channel_tick_interval,60000},
      {cluster_keepalive_interval,10000},
      {cluster_nodes,{[],disc}},
      {cluster_partition_handling,ignore},
      {collect_statistics,fine},
      {collect_statistics_interval,5000},
      {config_entry_decoder,[{passphrase,undefined}]},
      {connection_max,infinity},
      {credit_flow_default_credit,{400,200}},
      {default_consumer_prefetch,{false,0}},
      {default_permissions,[<<".*">>,<<".*">>,<<".*">>]},
      {default_user,<<"guest">>},
      {default_user_tags,[administrator]},
      {default_vhost,<<"/">>},
      {delegate_count,16},
      {disk_free_limit,50000000},
      {disk_monitor_failure_retries,10},
      {disk_monitor_failure_retry_interval,120000},
      {enabled_plugins_file,"/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins"},
      {feature_flags_file,
          "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490-feature_flags"},
      {fhc_read_buffering,false},
      {fhc_write_buffering,true},
      {frame_max,131072},
      {halt_on_upgrade_failure,true},
      {handshake_timeout,10000},
      {heartbeat,60},
      {lager_default_file,
          "/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490.log"},
      {lager_log_root,"/var/log/rabbitmq"},
      {lager_upgrade_file,
          "/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490_upgrade.log"},
      {lazy_queue_explicit_gc_run_operation_threshold,1000},
      {log,
          [{file,
               [{file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490.log"}]},
           {categories,
               [{upgrade,
                    [{file,
                         "/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490_upgrade.log"}]}]}]},
      {loopback_users,[<<"guest">>]},
      {max_message_size,134217728},
      {memory_monitor_interval,2500},
      {mirroring_flow_control,true},
      {mirroring_sync_batch_size,4096},
      {mnesia_table_loading_retry_limit,10},
      {mnesia_table_loading_retry_timeout,30000},
      {msg_store_credit_disc_bound,{4000,800}},
      {msg_store_file_size_limit,16777216},
      {msg_store_index_module,rabbit_msg_store_ets_index},
      {msg_store_io_batch_size,4096},
      {msg_store_shutdown_timeout,600000},
      {num_ssl_acceptors,10},
      {num_tcp_acceptors,10},
      {password_hashing_module,rabbit_password_hashing_sha256},
      {plugins_dir,
          "/usr/lib/rabbitmq/plugins:/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.8.9/plugins"},
      {plugins_expand_dir,
          "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@patricio-Latitude-7490-plugins-expand"},
      {proxy_protocol,false},
      {queue_explicit_gc_run_operation_threshold,1000},
      {queue_index_embed_msgs_below,4096},
      {queue_index_max_journal_entries,32768},
      {quorum_cluster_size,5},
      {quorum_commands_soft_limit,32},
      {reverse_dns_lookups,false},
      {server_properties,[]},
      {ssl_allow_poodle_attack,false},
      {ssl_apps,[asn1,crypto,public_key,ssl]},
      {ssl_cert_login_from,distinguished_name},
      {ssl_handshake_timeout,20000},
      {ssl_listeners,[5671]},
      {ssl_options,
          [{keyfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/server_key.pem"},
           {certfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/server_certificate.pem"},
           {cacertfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ca_certificate.pem"},
           {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false},
           {verify,verify_peer}]},
      {tcp_listen_options,
          [{backlog,128},
           {nodelay,true},
           {linger,{true,0}},
           {exit_on_close,false}]},
      {tcp_listeners,[{"auto",5672}]},
      {trace_vhosts,[]},
      {vhost_restart_strategy,continue},
      {vm_memory_calculation_strategy,rss},
      {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
      {vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio,0.5},
      {writer_gc_threshold,1000000000}]},
 {rabbit_common,[]},
 {rabbitmq_management,
     [{content_security_policy,
          "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'"},
      {cors_allow_origins,[]},
      {cors_max_age,1800},
      {http_log_dir,none},
      {load_definitions,"/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"},
      {management_db_cache_multiplier,5},
      {process_stats_gc_timeout,300000},
      {stats_event_max_backlog,250}]},
 {rabbitmq_management_agent,
     [{rates_mode,basic},
      {sample_retention_policies,
          [{global,[{605,5},{3660,60},{29400,600},{86400,1800}]},
           {basic,[{605,5},{3600,60}]},
           {detailed,[{605,5}]}]}]},
 {rabbitmq_prelaunch,[]},
 {rabbitmq_prometheus,[{return_per_object_metrics,false}]},
 {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,[]},
 {ranch,[]},
 {recon,[]},
 {sasl,[{errlog_type,error},{sasl_error_logger,false}]},
 {ssl,[{dtls_protocol_version,['dtlsv1.2']},{protocol_version,['tlsv1.2']}]},
 {stdlib,[]},
 {stdout_formatter,[]},
 {syntax_tools,[]},
 {sysmon_handler,
     [{busy_dist_port,true},
      {busy_port,false},
      {gc_ms_limit,0},
      {heap_word_limit,0},
      {port_limit,100},
      {process_limit,100},
      {schedule_ms_limit,0}]},
 {tools,[{file_util_search_methods,[{[],[]},{"ebin","esrc"},{"ebin","src"}]}]},
 {xmerl,[]}]
```

I'm running rabbitmq-server like this:

```
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
```

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.8.9

In order to verify the certificates I have tried starting an openssl server like so:

```
openssl s_server -accept 8444 \
  -cert server_certificate.pem -key server_key.pem -CAfile ca_certificate.pem
```

and connecting again using openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8444 -cert client_certificate.pem -key client_key.pem -CAfile ca_certificate.pem
```

And I get a successful connection.

Thanks in advance